# EclipseLink refuses to map native query on PostgreSQL to entity

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have a JPA entity class (one of many) and I can run JPQL queries on it, returning that entity without any problem. However, when I attempt to run any named native query that selects all the fields on the underlying table, instead of mapping to the entity and returning a list of that entity type, I get a `java.util.Vector` of object arrays containing the result set. That is, the data is being returned, but not mapped to the entity. This is made worse by Java's fake generics, because the error manifests itself as a `NumberFormatException` in the EL parser.

My query calling code:

```
return em.createNamedQuery("ClinicDoctor.findUnchangedByClinicSystemId",
                           ClinicDoctor.class)
    .setParameter(1, clinicSystemId)
    .getResultList();
```

When I switch EclipseLink logging to FINE and run a JPQL query, the column names selected exactly match the column names I'm selecting in the native query.

Am I missing something? Is there some flaming hoop I should be jumping through to get the mapping to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you know it, right after asking this question I discovered that I just had to set the `result-class` attribute on the `<named-native-query/>` tag in my orm.xml and it worked.